defaultdict ignores its default_factory argument when assigned explicitly
I ran into this problem when working with defaultdict. Here's a program that demonstrates it:
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(default_factory=dict)
d2 = defaultdict(dict)

print("d1's default_factory:", d1.default_factory)
print("d2's default_factory:", d2.default_factory)

try:
    d1['key'].update({'a': 'b'})
except KeyError:
    print("d1 caused an exception")

try:
    d2['key'].update({'a': 'b'})
except KeyError:
    print("d2 caused an exception")

The above outputs:
d1's default_factory: None
d2's default_factory: <class 'dict'>
d1 caused an exception

Should this happen?

defaultdict(default_factory=dict) created a dict with no default factory, containing "default_factory" as a key (with corresponding value dict).  The documentation could be a bit clearer that the factory parameter is positional-only - but it does explicitly say "All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments.".

@jasonharper: The docs have a positional-only marker, the / after the default_factory argument, but so many people have no idea what the / means.

default_factory is a positional-only argument. It cannot be passed by keyword.
d1 = defaultdict(default_factory=dict) creates a defaultdict with no default factory and a key 'default_factory' with value dict. It's as if you did
d1 = defaultdict()
d1['default_factory'] = dict

